# Conditional Content if State Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have two successful ways to display map markers based on my data API. This code displays all map markers on the map:

```
/// Working Code Option 1 (No Filters) ///
 this.state = {
      filterCrime: '',
      posts: []
}

   {this.state.posts.map((user, index)=> {
       return (
        <MapView.Marker key={user.ID} coordinate={{latitude: user.lat, longitude: user.lng}} />
          );
                 })}
```

This code successfully filters markers based on the filterCrime value and this works.

```
/// Working Code Option 2 (With Category Filters) ///
 this.state = {
      filterCrime: '',
      posts: []
}

   {this.state.posts.map((user, index)=> {
        if(user.category == this.state.filterCrime ){
       return (

        <MapView.Marker key={user.ID} coordinate={{latitude: user.lat, longitude: user.lng}} />
          );
                 }})}
```

My problem is this: If the filterCrime value is empty I want too display Option 1 which shows all map markers, otherwise, if the filterCrime state has an value I want to display Option 2 and show only filtered markers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just do a conditional on if the filter is there or not.

```
{this.state.posts.map((user, index)=> {
    if ( !this.state.filterCrime || user.category == this.state.filterCrime ) {
        return <MapView.Marker key={user.ID} coordinate={{latitude: user.lat, longitude: user.lng}} />
    }
    return null
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the array before using map on it.

```js
this.state = { filterCrime: '', posts: [] }

let filteredPosts = this.state.posts
if (filterCrime) {
  filteredPosts = filteredPosts.filter(post => post.category === this.state.filterCrime)
}

/* map from "Code Option 1" */
```